# Mix categories and subtasks in HighCharts Gantt?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I was experimenting a bit with HighCharts Gantt and I'm feeling like it is not possible to have both subtasks and tasks on the same 'row'. Am I wrong ?

[Subtask demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/subtasks/)

[Task on same line demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/interactive-gantt/)

As you can see, sub-tasking is achieved by referencing other task's ID like so :

```
data: [{
    id: 'task-1',
    ...
  }, {
    id: 'sub-task-1.1',
    parent: 'task-1'
    ...
  }]
```

while "multiple tasks on one line" is done by declaring yAxis categories and then referencing them by index:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['Tech', 'Marketing', 'Sales']
}
```

and later

```
data: [{
    y: 0
}]
```

As I said, it seems to me that achieving both is impossible. I am not just interested in having a different style for the category labels, this could probably be achieved with some CSS classes, but instead I'd like to **fold/reveal tasks and sub-tasks containing multiple tasks in the same line.**

Is is achievable ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not supported yet.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thought so :/ Thanks for confirming, I posted the [idea on userVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/37040539-mixing-categories-and-subtasks-in-highcharts-gantt) in case more are interested in such feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can somewhat do that using

```
yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true
}
```

and then defining the "categories" with the `name` of the data (those with the exact same one will be on the same "line").

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pamo6c0v/9/) but ignore the "remove" button as it is used to show some serious shenanigans happening that I have yet to find the cause of (probably my config, but maybe this isn't perfectly supported yet. I'm far from being an expert).